# lint errors making the code change but not sure how to proceed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typescript, kendo-ui

**updated.**

I updated the code like this but still I am getting the below error

**error**
 Type 'String' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  'string' is a primitive, but 'String' is a wrapper object. Prefer using 'string' when possible

**updated code**

```
    public sportsService: string;

  constructor( sportsService: String) {
    this.sportsService = sportsService;
  }
```

- I am new to tslint and typescript.
- I am trying to fix this error.
  **Property 'waterService' cannot be declared in the constructor**
- happening at this line
    constructor(public sportsService: SPORTSService) {}
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- i did some research but not able to find solutions.
- providing code below.
- even looked at this link and tried but not able to proceed

https://github.com/Microsoft/tslint-microsoft-contrib

**Property 'waterService' cannot be declared in the constructor**

```or-tag-here
/** Trees for contract and title. */
import {
  Component,
  Inject,
  OnInit,
  EventEmitter,
  ViewChild,
  Input,
  Output
}
from '@angular/core';
import {
  SPORTSService
}
from '../../services/sports.service';
import {
  KendoGridComponent
}
from '../grid/grid.component';
import {
  KendoDialog
}
from '../shared/kendoDialog/kendodialog';
import {
  ProgressCircle
}
from '../shared/progress/progress-circle';

declare let $: any;



@Component({
  selector: 'player',
  template: `<div id="windowcontainer"></div>`
})

export class player implements OnInit {

  private henInfoPopUpWindow;
  private airDate;
  private airTime;
  private showTitle;


  @Input() kendoCommandObj: any;




  constructor(public sportsService: SPORTSService) {}

  private kendocommand = {
    edit: {
      createAt: "bottom"
    },
    group: false,
    reorder: true,
    disableFreeze: true,
    resize: true,
    sort: true,
    autoBind: true,
    filter: false,
    pager: {
      messages: {
        //display: "Showing {0} to {1} of {2} entries"
      }
    },
    model: {},
    columns: [],
    pagesize: 50,
    getComponentUrl: "swimming",
    searchFields: [],
    mandatoryFields: [],
    saveStatus: false
  };


  @Output() applyAPTInfo: EventEmitter < any > = new EventEmitter < any > ();
  @Output('mouseCount') getTreeEvent = new EventEmitter<number>();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mouseType = 'hen';
    let that = this;
    let attributes=this.sportsService.getSeesionStorageValue();
```

Comment: Does your SPORTSService service have a constructor?

Comment: @kyle its here right   constructor(public sportsService: SPORTSService) {}

Comment: @texi.rv, I understand that you're injecting SPORTSService into Player, but does the SPORTSService have it's own injector?  Where is waterService coming from more specifically? It isn't in any of your code

Answer (score 2):

TSLint has a rule that disallows the use of constructor properties (i.e. when you prefix a constructor parameter with an accessor keyword like `public` or `private`).

```
"no-parameter-properties": true
```

In my opinion, this is a nonsensical rule, because I would much rather see:

```
class Example {
    constructor(private name: string) {}
}
```

And I don't want to see:

```
class Example {
    private name: string;
    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

In other words, [stop manually assigning TypeScript constructor parameters](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2013/04/stop-manually-assigning-typescript-constructor-parameters/)!

## Fix

Simply switch off the rule:

```
"no-parameter-properties": false
```

## Fix 2

For your second error, you have used the `String` interface in your type annotation. The fix for this is to follow the TSLint rule, as it is sound, and use `string`, `number`, `boolean`, etc where using primitive types in type annotations.

```
let x: String; // <-- interface String

let y: string; // <-- primitive type string
```

Additionally, it is pretty much a rule to follow in plain JavaScript too, where it is preferable to use literals, rather than objects:

```
let x = 'A literal string value here'; // <-- literal

let y = new String('String object'); // <-- object
```

Comment: If you don't want to change your TSLint config, you will have to manually map your parameters to properties. That's what I have shown in the second Example class - with the separate property declaration, the removal of the `private` keyword in the constructor, and the mapping inside the constructor.

Comment: i am confused...can you tell me why we need to do like that

Comment: You _don't_ need to do it like that, but you have told TSLint to force you to do it like that.

Comment: I updated the code like this but still I am getting the below error---->
 Type 'String' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  'string' is a primitive, but 'String' is a wrapper object. Prefer using 'string' when possible -----------> 
        public sportsService: string;
    
      constructor( sportsService: String) {
        this.sportsService = sportsService;
      }

Comment: Lower case your "s" -> ` constructor( sportsService: string) {`

Answer (score 1):

this is a good rule of tslint,
it means always use primitive type names
and not primitive type constructors

**you should replace:**

- `String` with `string`
- `Boolean` with `boolean`
- `Number` with `number`

If you interested what the difference is, check this links:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number